# Connecting to Active Directory to retrieve user details using C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, active-directory

I found an article about getting users from active directory from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/adtester.aspx)

So possibly my code will like this

```
String strPath = "format of this path";
DirectoryEntry entry = null;
entry = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);

DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

mySearcher.Filter = ("ObjectCategory=user");

foreach (SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
    String strName = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
    //Do whatever
}
```

Can you please explain the strPath here ?? What is format of this ??

Note: I know my server information can get using my local ip "198.168.1.182" for testing purposes.

I am not sure the way I am thinking is correct.

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 4, you should definitely check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find user by name
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "John Doe");

// if we found user - inspect its details
if(user != null)
{
    string firstName = user.GivenName;
    string lastName = user.Surname;
    string email = user.EmailAddress;
    string phone = user.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Comment: answer by marc_s is not complete. The FindyByIntenty method requires minimum of two arguments. The principal context object "ctx" needs to be first argument.

Comment: @jdmorris: thanks, you're absolutely right - corrected my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for a solution all day. This made it very simple and easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

strPath is the LDAP URL, on which more information can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP#LDAP_URLs

The structure may look a bit strange at first but the example at wikipedia gives a nice summary of it.